# Backlog Calculation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I need to create a report that calculates the accumulated ticket backlog, but I can not get the correct result. I already tested several solutions that I found on the internet, but I'm stagnant.

```
    -- CREATE TABLE
    create table #tickets
    (
        ano          int,
        mes          int,
        nmusuario    nvarchar(100),
        qtd_abertos  int,
        qtd_fechados int
    )

    -- INSERT SAMPLE DATA
    insert into #tickets values 
     (2017,6, 'Analyst 1',38 ,55)
    ,(2017,7, 'Analyst 1',69 ,69)
    ,(2017,8, 'Analyst 1',74 ,73)
    ,(2017,9, 'Analyst 1',90 ,89)
    ,(2017,10,'Analyst 1',86 ,87)
    ,(2017,11,'Analyst 1',142,137)
    ,(2017,12,'Analyst 1',90 ,101)
    ,(2018,1, 'Analyst 1',20 ,15)
    ,(2018,2, 'Analyst 1',0  ,2)

    -- SHOW SAMPLE
    select * from #tickets

    +------+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+
    | ano  | mes | nmusuario  | qtd_abertos | qtd_fechados |
    +------+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+
    | 2017 |   6 |  Analyst 1 |          38 |           55 |
    | 2017 |   7 |  Analyst 1 |          69 |           69 |
    | 2017 |   8 |  Analyst 1 |          74 |           73 |
    | 2017 |   9 |  Analyst 1 |          90 |           89 |
    | 2017 |  10 | Analyst 1  |          86 |           87 |
    | 2017 |  11 | Analyst 1  |         142 |          137 |
    | 2017 |  12 | Analyst 1  |          90 |          101 |
    | 2018 |   1 |  Analyst 1 |          20 |           15 |
    | 2018 |   2 |  Analyst 1 |           0 |            2 |
    +------+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+

    -- QUERY TO MEASURE BACKLOG
    select 
         ano
        ,mes
        ,nmusuario
        ,qtd_abertos
        ,qtd_fechados
        ,(select 
                sum(qtd_abertos - qtd_fechados)
           from 
                #tickets 
           where 
                    mes <= a.mes
                and ano <= a.ano
                and nmusuario = a.nmusuario) as backlog 
    from 
        #tickets a

+------+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| ano  | mes | nmusuario  | qtd_abertos | qtd_fechados | backlog |
+------+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| 2017 |   6 |  Analyst 1 |          38 |           55 |     -17 |
| 2017 |   7 |  Analyst 1 |          69 |           69 |     -17 |
| 2017 |   8 |  Analyst 1 |          74 |           73 |     -16 |
| 2017 |   9 |  Analyst 1 |          90 |           89 |     -15 |
| 2017 |  10 | Analyst 1  |          86 |           87 |     -16 |
| 2017 |  11 | Analyst 1  |         142 |          137 |     -11 |
| 2017 |  12 | Analyst 1  |          90 |          101 |     -22 |
| 2018 |   1 |  Analyst 1 |          20 |           15 |       5 |
| 2018 |   2 |  Analyst 1 |           0 |            2 |       3 |
+------+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
```

But the correct result should be

```
+------+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| ano  | mes | nmusuario  | qtd_abertos | qtd_fechados | backlog |
+------+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
| 2017 |   6 |  Analyst 1 |          38 |           55 |      17 | 38-55=17
| 2017 |   7 |  Analyst 1 |          69 |           69 |      17 | 17+69-69=17
| 2017 |   8 |  Analyst 1 |          74 |           73 |      18 | 17+74-73=18
| 2017 |   9 |  Analyst 1 |          90 |           89 |      19 | 18+90-89=19
| 2017 |  10 | Analyst 1  |          86 |           87 |      18 | 19+86-87=18
| 2017 |  11 | Analyst 1  |         142 |          137 |      23 | 18+142-137=23
| 2017 |  12 | Analyst 1  |          90 |          101 |      12 | 23+90-101=12
| 2018 |   1 |  Analyst 1 |          20 |           15 |      17 | 12+20-15=17
| 2018 |   2 |  Analyst 1 |           0 |            2 |      15 | 17+0-2=15
+------+-----+------------+-------------+--------------+---------+
```

Comment: In the first backlog you want `38
- 55` to be positive `= 17`. In the 5th one you want `86 - 87` to be negative and subtract one from the backlog (backlog went from `19 to 18`). Which is it?

Comment: @RandiVertongen, we need to add qtd_ready with the backlog from the previous month and subtract qtd_fechados to get the new backlog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by following the tips of this site:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/654f83c1-2843-412d-81d4-8af24e15e063/somatrio-de-backlog

I hope it helps others.